# How to move FlexibleSpaceBar to center on SliverAppbar scroll

Tags: flutter

I wanted to be able to have the settings title (which is in the flexible space bar) move into the center when the user scrolls up. How can I do this?

I have linked a video of my current screen when I scroll. As you can see the settings title goes to the left hand side not the center when the user scrolls up.

https://youtu.be/59MACs8jeAk

Here is my code for the screen (not all of it just the part that is relevant):

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => 
                         Navigator.pop(context),
                          //controller.toggle();
                          icon: Image.asset('assets/UI/menu.png')),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            expandedHeight: 145.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            //floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            elevation: 0.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Row(
                children: <Widget>[

                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Settings',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 22.0),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
              background: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 32, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Change Settings',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            fontSize: 16.0),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test your piece of code, but it didn't work. But, you can try to replace this part:

```
title: Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 0, 0, 0),
child: Text(
  'Settings',
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 22.0),
)),
```

Comment: Hi Vitor, I used the part of the code that is relevant otherwise it would be to long, unfortunately this doesn't work as the text stays in the center the whole time, I want it on the left hand side when it is extended and then in the center when the sliver appbar is collapsed. Thanks